# How to evaluate the following sum

Tags: summation, summation-method

While studying sequences and series, I came across summations of geometric series. I am able to derive the sum of a geometric progression and that of arithmetico–geometric sequence.

But what do you call a series where the $i^{th}$ term is $a^{i^2}$?
And how can we evaluate its sum?

$$
S = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^{i^2}
$$

I tried multiplying $S$ by $a$ and differentiating it by $a$ but to no avail.

Comment: I don't think there's a special name for this. But if you compare to a comvergent geometric series, this sum (in limit) should comverge.